# Way to obscure SQL Server database schema?

Tags: obfuscation, sql-server-express, database-schema

Is there any way to obscure the schema of a database on SQL Server?

If I have SQL Server Express installed on a client site, is there a way to obscure the schema and data so that someone else cannot come along and learn the schema in order to extract data out of it and into another product?

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing better than locking clients into your upgrade path. They love that.

Comment: As a less sarcastic comment - which product is likely to be better - the one where the developers spend time working on features the customers want, or the one where the developers spend time trying to prevent the clients moving to a better product? - it's a vicious spiral.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: wouldn't it make commercial sense to do that? Why should data that is structured by my own design be free and open to everyone else?

Comment: @CraigJ - Damien's point is that your time (and hence, money) is better spent on making features that customers want and keeping them happy rather than spending time on making features _you_ want and that piss customers off. Commercial sense is things that make money. Happy customers that have the features they need makes sense. Pissing them off and letting competitors make new features while you do it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Reminds me of something that Ayende posed as a joke.  http://ayende.com/blog/4048/nhibernate-get-thou-out-of-my-database

Comment: What are you even writing that needs this level of paranoia?

Comment: I'm not going to down vote you but I think that ultimately, your users own their data.  Also, I personally find the idea of that level of lock in very distasteful.

Comment: From experience, the harder you make if for a client to own your product means that when things go wrong, and they can't fix it or use it, then they remember this. When it comes round to upgrade time (or if enough issues accumulate) then they'll no longer be your client. Also note that many clients, especially government ones, now stipulate open (and not proprierary) data formats and storage, to prevent lock in. Why reduce your client pool when you can focus on the features that will really sell it. Anything else should probably be in your contract with them.

Comment: Obviously you guys have never written medical software or similar - I work in a health-based industry where the barrier to entry for a competing implementation is massive - giving them a working DB Schema to start from would be a huge leg up.

Comment: I always wonder about this kind of thing; Why wouldn't specifying in the terms and conditions for the software that this isn't allowed be sufficient?

Comment: If your schema was valuable, you wouldn't use SQL Server Express. I've banned this before as a DBA: if you want to install it, we don't use your product

Comment: @Daniel James Bryars: agree: should all be licensing

Comment: @gbn: What is the problem with SQL Server Express?  If you're installing the product for a business that employs 2 people, eg. a professional and a secretary, then why on earth would that business buy a SQL Server licence?

Comment: @CraigJ: The trade off of effort to obscure the database to run on a free product for a 2 person business? It doesn't make sense. If you are targeting large companies, they'll have DBAs who may ban SQL Server Express.

Comment: @gbn: the size of the business doesn't matter - you would still want to obscure it.  Are you talking about Oracle-only shops that would ban SQL Server?

Comment: @CraigJ: no, I'm a SQL Server DBA who would ban it. I know several large MS shops that ban it.

Comment: @gbn: if a large company already runs a SQL Server then you wouldn't need Express anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one and may not even be 100% possible. However, there are a few tricks to setting it up:

1. Install a new *named* instance of SQL server with a custom SA account (both name and password). There is an installation method for SQL server call "Unattended Installation" which allows you to specify all the installation parameters for SQL server in an ini file and then run the install silently. Check out the documentation here: [Unattended Installation of SQL Server 2008 r2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693561.aspx)
2. Create your database, tables, procedures, etc. with your magic SQL install script (use encrypted stored procs if you want, but they too are crackable)
3. Add/Verify the schema permissions for the *custom* SA account and Drop all schema permissions for all Administrator roles. The goal here is that no *roles* have any schema permissions to your database and only your custom SA *user* has permission (not assigned by role, but directly to the user).

There are several commercial applications that I know of that don't even tell you they are installing an instance of MS SQL express. They too will create their own named instance with a named SA account. I can't say I like that as a customer (as SQL takes a hit on the CPU and I don't want "secret" instances running on my workstation). But so long as you disclose this to your customers upfront, they may understand.

**Keep in mind a skilled DBA may have the knowledge to mess with system tables and what not to manually grant access to your database. These techniques really are just "obfuscation" and won't be 100% bullet proof.

---

**As a side note:** With the plethora of available 3rd party datalayers and webservice technologies, I think many companies are finding their database schema alone isn't so proprietary or valuable anymore. There was a time when the database schema alone could have represented hundreds of hours of coding. But today tools like EntityFramework, NHibernate, Linq-to-SQL, XPO, etc all create your database schema for you based on your software class definitions and in code attributes. So just seeing a DB table isn't really very valuable. Plus you might write a bunch of business logic, statistical analysis or other helper methods in your software that aren't in your database schema. In my opinion, this is where today's "*value add*" is found, in the business logic, analysis and reporting functionality of your software - not in the raw datatables.

This is also why another poster recommended obfuscating stored procedures, because these could be many times the work of the database schema itself if you have some nice analysis and reporting procedures written up. Its also what customer's would most likely want to customize for their own reporting needs. You may be inclined to have a policy that custom reporting can only be done by your company (hey, even the big guys like SAP are sticky with who can modify what).

Comment: Obsfucation would however potentially prevent a competitor product from extracting the data out of your product and into their's.

Comment: I awarded this answer because it seems the most sensible way to achieve the kind of obsfucation I am looking for.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to obscure your database schema is to not let it leave your servers.

Even if you encrypt the schema you still will have to provide the key somewhere, and if the client is determined to get it, they'll spend time and money to do so.

So you're better off either offering your product as service or making your client loyal by doing good job.

Comment: what do you mean by offer product as 'service'? Do you mean like monthly fees?

Comment: @CraigJ yes. Unless you can't, try to leave as much of your code as you can on your servers. Preferably accessible by thin client. Make your customers pay monthly or yearly fees. Practically it's the only way you can make sure your code is secure and you get paid for what you do. Also it makes upgrades much easier. If your app is a fat client, make some very important functionality subscriber-only and available via network conection on your server. This model of distribution is called [Software as a service (SaaS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)

Comment: If you don't believe it's the only way take a look at MS and all the obstacles they put in front of windows crackers and how far it got them. Granted, there are other parameters, like more people interested in cracked Windows, but there's probably more people fighting the crackers in MS than there is in your company as well. In general it's a waste of time that could be better spent doing actual development.

Comment: +1 Because this is the only way to *actually* achieve this, and it avoids treating your clients as if they were common thieves.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, "no".

The best way to "lock down" your database is:

1) Install with appropriate roles and users (ideally, SQL roles and SQL users *you* create)

2) Explicitly restrict object permissions in SQL Server

3) Code your application to use SQL Server stored procedures (instead of raw T-SQL) as much as possible

4) Encrypt your stored procedures

Here's a good link on "SQL Server Best Practices" that might be of interest.  It discusses security issues and a (relatively) new feature, "User Schema Separation":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Why would using stored procedures obscure the schema more?

Comment: @CraigJ: Raw SQL can be logged, but stored procedures can be controlled with access permissions. Only the user for your application can run them / see them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, it's convoluted and ugly but it works.

You have a master table that acts as a lookup table for your other tables. This master table would look sort of like this:

id, guid, entityname, parent_id

then all of your table names and column names get renamed to be guids.  after that you put an entry in the lookup table for each of them.  When you want to select data you have to do so by pulling the guid's out of the lookup table by their entitynames which then give you the obscured table and column names.

There is a major software vendor out there that does something very similar to this, so it has been done before.

Comment: Good idea, but probably a bit drastic for my circumstances.

Comment: @CraigJ Your whole idea is 'drastic', to be honest.

Comment: I agree it's drastic i also agree you shouldn't do it.