# How can I encrypt a distributable SQL Server Express database?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, encryption, sql-server-express

We have a product that historically uses a Microsoft Access database which is great because it is portable.

However we are looking to move to SQL Server and this will range from the Express version upwards. In the Access database we can use a password to protect the database from prying eyes. Although I appreciate it only offers limited security. We need to be able to protect a SQL Server database however we do have access to the server as the database is delivered as part of the install. The client would install SQL Server and then attach the database. I looked at NetLib but that requires an install on the server. I cannot use TDE as SQL Express does not support that. I can use column encryption but I was wondering if there was a database wide solution. Basically no one except for us as supplier should be able to query the data unless they use our software interface.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265664/way-to-obscure-sql-server-database-schema) is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you are willing to consider a third party product, there are at least two that can provide TDE to SQL Express. Ours Is [Encryptionizer for SQL Server](https://netlibsecurity.com) and another is DBEncrypt. They work differently though: Encryptionizer sits between the SQL Server process and the OS, while DBEncrypt injects itself into the SQL Server process in memory using that old Detours SDK (no longer available SFAIK).

Comment: SQL Server [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) might be an option, but you need to manage your keys in a way to keep unrestricted users from accessing it